# Problemas com o GridView (Android) para exibir dados

Tags: android-layout, gridview

Pessoal sou novo em programação para Android e estou com um problema em relação a uma situação em um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo usando o GridView com uma classe Adaptador e uma lista de itens(objeto) vinda de uma webservice. Gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

Resultado do WebService trazendo uma lista de pacientes com os seguintes dados: Cartão SUS e o Nome. O cartao sus tem a função de identificação do paciente, no banco ele e chave primaria.

```
Result from post JsonPost : 200 : {"paciente":
[{"cartaoSus":"123456789","nome":"Fábio"},
{"cartaoSus":"123456789111111","nome":"Teste"},
{"cartaoSus":"22222222222","nome":"Paulo"},{"cartaoSus":"33333333333","nome":"Maria"}]}
```

Principal

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;
import br.com.sistemaid.modelo.Adaptador;
import br.com.sistemaid.modelo.Paciente;
import br.com.sistemaid.webservice.ClienteREST;

public class PrincipalActivity extends Activity {

GridView gv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal_grid);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    listarPacientesInternados();
}

public void listarPacientesInternados() {

    ClienteREST cliREST = new ClienteREST();

    gv = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.monitor_grid);

    try {

        ArrayList<Paciente> pacientesAtendidos = (ArrayList<Paciente>) cliREST
                .ListarPacientes();
        gv.setAdapter(new Adaptador(this, pacientesAtendidos));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.principal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Adaptador

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import br.com.sistemaid.R;

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Paciente> lista;

public Adaptador(Context context, ArrayList<Paciente> lista) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Paciente getItem(int posicao) {
    return lista.get(posicao);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int posicao) {
    return posicao;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    PacienteViewHolder pacienteVH = new PacienteViewHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_principal_grid, parent, false);

        pacienteVH.nomePaciente = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        convertView.setTag(pacienteVH);
    } else {
        pacienteVH = (PacienteViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;

}

static class PacienteViewHolder {
    TextView nomePaciente;
}

}
```

Layout da Activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FF2552"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="br.com.sistemaid.PrincipalActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/monitor_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout da linha Row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com.sistemaid"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".PrincipalActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Fazendo algumas modificações no sistema e colocando para fazer printstacktrace, começou a ser exibido esse erro no logcat:
[image: erro]

Minha função de retorna a lista dos pacientes é

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import br.com.sistemaid.modelo.Paciente;
import br.com.sistemaid.webservice.WebServiceCliente;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class PacienteControle {

private static final String URL_WS = 
            "http://192.168.1.106:8080/ID-WebService/paciente/";

public List<Paciente> listarPacientes() throws Exception {

    String[] resposta = new WebServiceCliente().get(URL_WS
            + "listarPacientes");

    if (resposta[0].equals("200")) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Paciente> listaPacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonArray array = parser.parse(resposta[1]).getAsJsonArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            listaPacientes.add(gson.fromJson(array.get(i), Paciente.class));

        }
        return listaPacientes;

    } else {
        throw new Exception(resposta[1]);
    }
}

}
```

Na atual situação na tela do tablet aparece em branco. Alguma sugestão do que fazer??

Classe adaptadora depois das correções:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import br.com.sistemaid.R;

public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Paciente> lista;

public Adaptador(Context context, ArrayList<Paciente> lista) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Paciente getItem(int posicao) {
    return lista.get(posicao);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int posicao) {
    return posicao;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    PacienteViewHolder pacienteVH = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grade, parent, false);

        pacienteVH = new PacienteViewHolder();
        pacienteVH.nomePaciente =  (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        convertView.setTag(pacienteVH);
    } else {
        pacienteVH = (PacienteViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    pacienteVH.nomePaciente.setText(lista.get(position).getNomePaciente());

    return convertView;
}

static class PacienteViewHolder {
    Button nomePaciente;
}

}
```

Método listarPaciente

```
public List<Paciente> listarPacientes() throws Exception {

    String[] resposta = new WebServiceCliente().get(URL_WS
            + "listarPacientes");

    if (resposta[0].equals("200")) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Paciente> listaPacientes = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

        JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) parser.parse(resposta[1]).getAsJsonObject().get("paciente");

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.size(); i++) {
            listaPacientes.add(gson.fromJson(jArray.get(i), Paciente.class));
        }
        return listaPacientes;
    } else {
        throw new Exception(resposta[1]);
    }
}
```

Como fazer esse metodo funcionar?

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getParent(), ((Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1)).getText(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            }   
        });
```

Sendo que essa variavel v ele simplesmente desconhece.

Comment: Fabio, o problema é que o JSON do WebService não é um array, como o erro diz. Nele você tem um objeto cuja única propriedade é o array. Você teria que fazer: `parser.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("paciente")`.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração e o erro do JSON não é exibido mais. Porém o gridView ainda continua em branco, sem exibir os dados. Para verificar se o objeto não estava nulo depois dessa conversão eu coloquei para aparecer no log os dados e eles são exibidos corretamente, todos pacientes cadastrados no banco estão presentes.

Comment: Depois de fazer as devidas alterações e com um pouco mais de pesquisa. Consegui solucionar o problema. Notei que também não tinha instanciado o pacienteVH e que no inflate tinha colocado a referencia para o layout errado. Fiz uma edição na pergunta para postar os novos códigos. Porém tem outro problema depois da grid montada não estou conseguindo montar o código para o efeito de acionar o item da grid que acabei trocando para um button ao invés de um textView. Alguma recomendação para encontrar a solução?